# Removing white spaces after writing a file in aspx page

Tags: vb.net, whitespace

I am trying to remove white spaces created after writing file in aspx page. Below is the code for your reference:

```
<div class="wrapper" runat="server">
    <header class="main-header skin-blue">
        <%If Session("UserRole") = "Admin" Or Session("UserRole") = "TeamLead" Then
                Response.WriteFile("frmHeaderAdmin.aspx")
            Else
                Response.WriteFile("frmHeaderEmployee.aspx")
            End If %>
    </header>
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar" runat="server">
                <%If Session("Userrole") = "Admin" Then
                    Response.WriteFile("frmSideBarAdmin.aspx")
                ElseIf Session("Userrole") = "TeamLead" Then
                    Response.WriteFile("frmSideBarTL.aspx")
                Else
                    Response.WriteFile("frmSideBarUser.aspx")
                End If%>
    </aside>`enter code here`
</div>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong so that I can make necessary changes in the code

Comment: It looks to me like you should be using [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8)s. You can then set the `.Visible` property to show or hide them as appropriate. (Using Response.WriteFile in code like that usually shows something is not being done the intended way.)